# Query to find the tables size occupied in GB in Oracle SQL for various SCHEMAS

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, database-administration

I am trying to find the space occupied by list of tables in Oracle DB (for various SCHEMAS ) ,currently i am using this query

**QUERY 1 - DBA_SEGMENTS**

```
SELECT SEGMENT_NAME,SUM (BYTES)/1024/1024/1024 AS GB,
ROUND(100*RATIO_TO_REPORT(GB) OVER (), 4) PERCENTAGE  
FROM DBA_SEGMENTS
WHERE OWNER='SCHEMA_NAME'
AND SEGMENT_TYPE ='TABLE'
AND SEGMENT_NAME
IN
(
'LIST OF TABLES'
)
GROUP BY SEGMENT_NAME,BYTES
ORDER BY GB DESC;
```

**QUERY 2 - DBA_OBJECTS**

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME FROM DBA_OBJECTS
WHERE OWNER='SCHEMA'
AND OBJECT_NAME IN 
(
'LIST OF TABLES'
)
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME;
```

when i compare the LIST OF TABLES counts it's not matching , what could be the reason ?

can you please suggest is this correct or is there a better way to achieve this ?

Reference
https://serverfault.com/questions/132620/oracle-how-to-find-out-storage-space-used-by-a-table

**Additional Query 1**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  input_owner         NVARCHAR2(128) := 'SCHEMA_NAME';
  segment_size_blocks NUMBER;
  segment_size_bytes  NUMBER;
  used_blocks         NUMBER;
  used_bytes          NUMBER;
  expired_blocks      NUMBER;
  expired_bytes       NUMBER;
  unexpired_blocks    NUMBER;
  unexpired_bytes     NUMBER;
  total_blocks        NUMBER;
  total_bytes         NUMBER;
  unused_blocks       NUMBER;
  unused_bytes        NUMBER;
  last_ext_file_id    NUMBER;
  last_ext_blk_id     NUMBER;
  last_used_blk       NUMBER;
  result_table        NVARCHAR2(128);
  result_segment_type NVARCHAR2(128);
  result_used_mb      NUMBER;
  result_unused_mb    NUMBER;
  result_total_mb     NUMBER;
  CURSOR cur
  IS
    SELECT
      s.segment_name   AS segment_name,
      s.owner          AS segment_owner,
      s.partition_name AS partition_name,
      s.segment_type   AS segment_type,
      CASE WHEN s.segment_type IN ('TABLE', 'TABLE PARTITION', 'TABLE SUBPARTITION')
        THEN s.segment_name
      WHEN s.segment_type IN ('INDEX', 'INDEX PARTITION', 'INDEX SUBPARTITION')
        THEN (SELECT i.table_name
              FROM dba_indexes i
              WHERE s.segment_name = i.index_name AND s.owner = i.owner)
      WHEN s.segment_type IN ('LOBSEGMENT', 'LOB PARTITION')
        THEN (SELECT l.table_name
              FROM dba_lobs l
              WHERE s.segment_name = l.segment_name AND s.owner = l.owner)
      WHEN s.segment_type IN ('LOBINDEX')
        THEN (SELECT l.table_name
              FROM dba_lobs l
              WHERE s.segment_name = l.index_name AND s.owner = l.owner)
      ELSE 'Unknown'
      END              AS table_name,
      s.bytes          AS segment_bytes
    FROM dba_segments s
    WHERE owner = input_owner
    and segment_name in 
    (

    )
    ORDER BY table_name, segment_type;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('table                         ; segment type        ;   used (mb)     ; unused (mb)     ;  total (mb)');

  FOR ro IN cur
  LOOP

    result_table := ro.table_name;
    result_segment_type := ro.segment_type;

    IF ro.segment_type IN ('TABLE', 'INDEX')
    THEN
      dbms_space.unused_space(
          segment_owner             => ro.segment_owner,
          segment_name              => ro.segment_name,
          segment_type              => ro.segment_type,
          total_blocks              => total_blocks,
          total_bytes               => total_bytes,
          unused_blocks             => unused_blocks,
          unused_bytes              => unused_bytes,
          last_used_extent_file_id  => last_ext_file_id,
          last_used_extent_block_id => last_ext_blk_id,
          last_used_block           => last_used_blk);

      result_used_mb := (total_bytes - unused_bytes) / 1024 / 1024;
      result_unused_mb := unused_bytes / 1024 / 1024;
      result_total_mb := total_bytes / 1024 / 1024;

    ELSIF ro.segment_type IN ('LOBSEGMENT')
    THEN
      dbms_space.space_usage(
          segment_owner           => ro.segment_owner,
          segment_name            => ro.segment_name,
          segment_type            => 'LOB',
          partition_name          => ro.partition_name,
          segment_size_blocks     => segment_size_blocks,
          segment_size_bytes      => segment_size_bytes,
          used_blocks             => used_blocks,
          used_bytes              => used_bytes,
          expired_blocks          => expired_blocks,
          expired_bytes           => expired_bytes,
          unexpired_blocks        => unexpired_blocks,
          unexpired_bytes         => unexpired_bytes
      );
      result_used_mb := used_bytes / 1024 / 1024;
      result_unused_mb := (segment_size_bytes - used_bytes) / 1024 / 1024;
      result_total_mb := segment_size_bytes / 1024 / 1024;
    ELSE
      -- TODO ??
      result_used_mb := ro.segment_bytes / 1024 / 1024;
      result_unused_mb := 0;
      result_total_mb := result_used_mb + result_unused_mb;
    END IF;

    dbms_output.put_line(
        RPAD(result_table, 30) || '; ' ||
        RPAD(result_segment_type, 20)|| '; ' ||
        TO_CHAR(result_used_mb  / 1024 / 1024, '999999999990D00')|| '; ' ||
        TO_CHAR(result_unused_mb  / 1024 / 1024, '999999999990D00')|| '; ' ||
        TO_CHAR(result_total_mb / 1024 / 1024, '999999999990D00'));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

**Additional Query 2**

```
WITH DA AS (
 SELECT OWNER, SEGMENT_NAME, SUM(BYTES)/1024/1024 SIZE_MB
   FROM DBA_EXTENTS
   GROUP BY ROLLUP(OWNER, SEGMENT_NAME)
) SELECT OWNER, SEGMENT_NAME, SIZE_MB, ROUND(SIZE_MB/TOTAL_MB*100)
  FROM DA 
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT SIZE_MB AS TOTAL_MB 
      FROM DA T WHERE OWNER IS NULL AND SEGMENT_NAME IS NULL
    )
ORDER BY SIZE_MB DESC
```

Comment: Looks good; but it doesn't consider space used by indexes, LOBs, partitioned tables etc.  For general purposes, if you don't have partitioned tables that is fine, to quickly find "space hogs."  To account for partitioned tables, do a `AND SEGMENT_TYPE LIKE 'TABLE%'`

Comment: @MarkStewart - when i compare the LIST OF TABLES counts from QUERY 1 and QUERY 2 result are not matching , what could be the reason ? QUERY 1 retrieves only partial result

Comment: The `DBA_OBJECTS` query does not have a restriction on `OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'` (you did on the query for `DBA_SEGMENTS` -- you limited it to `SEGMENT_TYPE = 'TABLE'`.  And I assume you used the exact same value for `OWNER=` in both queries.  You may want to [edit] your question to sync that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fairly accurate query that takes tables, indexes, and any partitioned tables/indexes into account for all tables for a single schema owner.  Note that there will be some additional overhead in actual space used due to blocksize, file headers, etc.

```
  select segment_name
         , segment_type
         , sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 as GB
         , ROUND(100*RATIO_TO_REPORT(bytes) OVER (), 4) PERCENTAGE
  from dba_segments ds
  where
      owner ='SCOTT'
      and (
              segment_type like 'TABLE%'
              and segment_name in ('EMP', 'SALGRADE', 'EMP_BKP', 'DEPT')
          or
              (
                 segment_type like 'INDEX%'
                 and segment_name in (
                         select index_name from dba_indexes di
                             where owner ='SCOTT'
                               and di.table_name in ('EMP', 'SALGRADE', 'EMP_BKP', 'DEPT')
                         )
              -- more fun here for LOBs, etc.
             )
         )
  group by segment_name, segment_type, bytes
  order by GB desc;
```

Take a look at `DBA_LOBS` for additional criteria to add to the `-- more fun here` to pick up LOB information.

Comment: many thanks for the query , but one question why are we checking here for index ,since i just need to find out the space consumed only be list of selected tables ,basically if the tables consumed huge space must be dropped

Comment: If you don't have a bunch of indexes on tables, no worries; but sometimes (like an application I currently support) some tables have 8 indexes; others have 1 or 2; and sometimes those indexes can get big.  If my answer solved your question (or over-solved it!) feel free to mark it as accepted after a few days, in case someone else comes up with a more elegant solution, accept it instead; which I'm sure is easy.  I just tweaked your query with some scraps I I had laying around.

Comment: This is helpful i have also found one useful reference but i getting error https://serverfault.com/questions/132620/oracle-how-to-find-out-storage-space-used-by-a-table

Comment: Steward  - can you see Additional Query 1 and Query2 above and let me know any useful ?

Comment: The additional query you added gets into all the "miscellaneous overhead" I mentioned; all the extra information is of limited use; depending on all sorts of things; how information is inserted, updated, deleted, etc.  So it will certainly give a more accurate estimate of *at a certain point in time* about how much space is being used, but far better to just keep it simple, and try not to squeeze every last free GB of space out of your disks.  Trust me, I've had to try that a long time ago!